# Can I use row span on the last row of a table?

Tags: html, html-table

I want to make a 3 x 3 table which has Cell 4 spanning 2 rows below and insert Cell 5 below Cell 3. I tried adding a new row and add a cell into it, it occupies the spanning of cell 3 (adjacent to cell 4) instead of being directly below it.

Question is, how do I span cell 4 below (to make it 2 x 2) and add cell 5 beside it?

[image: Progress so far]

Code so far:

```
 <table border = "1" cellpadding="10">

    <tr>
      <td>Cell1</td>
      <td>Cell2</td>
      <td rowspan = 2>Cell3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan = "2" colspan = "2">Cell4</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

I want to make something like this:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Care to draw what you're after?

Comment: Done! My apologies for the messy drawing. @rybo111

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add another `<tr>`.

I added some css to make it more obvious:

```
tr{
    height: 25px;
}
```

here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zm72pyy4/). Explanation to follow briefly.

Explanation:

If the css is removed, you'll notice that the line **almost** disappears. That's because you practically don't have anything on that line. If you have another column of cells (either visible or invisible) which actually utilizes that row, the row will become visible.

This phenomenon happens because the height of the cells is auto, thus it shrinks to 0 when it's empty, which in your case happens because there is no cell that spreads only across on the aforementioned row.

### EDIT:

There used to be a html only way, by setting the height inside the table elements, but it's supposedly deprecated as of HTML5 and should be avoided at all costs. Use css instead! If, for some reason, you REALLY need the old html only solution, it's displayed [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zm72pyy4/1/). But it's a very very very very bad practice to use it, and it might not be compatible with some browsers and etc.

The same is valid for  `border = "1" cellpadding="10"` as pointed out in the comments :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very concise answer! In short, it's not do-able with just columns-rows spanning tags on it? (Without CSS or any other styling mechanism) @Hristo Valkanov

Comment: @Sai you could add the height style inside the [html element itself](http://jsfiddle.net/zm72pyy4/1/), but it's highly disapproved and supposedly, soon to be completely deprecated (supposedly it's not supported on HTML5). So it's ill advised to use the pure html solution.

Comment: Noted! I'd definitely keep that in mind. I'll choose this as the answer then. Thank you! @Hristo Valkanov

Comment: There is nothing particularly bad about setting height in table cells. At least not worse than using *other* presentational attributes, like `border` and `cellpadding` in the fiddle.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I copied the the code from the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an invisible spacer column first.

Also, here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tnc1z531/

```
<style>
    td
    {
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .spacer
    {
        border: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 30px;
    }
</style>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class='spacer'></td>
        <td>Cell1</td>
        <td>Cell2</td>
        <td rowspan=2>Cell3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='spacer'></td>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">Cell4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='spacer'></td>
        <td>Cell5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```